# Windows GUI SSH client

Tags: ssh, openssh

How can I connect with SSH certificates and PKCS#11 token from GUI client?

I need to provide SSH client with a signed SSH certificate file, PKCS#11 DLL and token PIN, but not SSH private key in file.

Command line OpenSSH client work fine, I specify CertificateFile and PKCS11Provider in config, type token PIN and it connects. However, I failed to implement anything like that with ZOC, XShell or SecureCRT. XShell was the closest, it supports PKCS#11 or SSH certificates, but not PKCS#11 and SSH certificates.

Comment: Questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic. I think in this case it's possible to ask like "how can I do this not in the command line?", therefore preventing the question from being closed. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: Everyone uses PuTTY

Comment: I'm more curious about, _what's the practical difference_ between running OpenSSH in Windows Terminal vs running e.g. PuTTY-CAC "graphically" if they both end up showing a terminal window anyway?

Comment: @user1686 In GUI you get fancy config windows specific to the application and sometimes obscure, instead of using well-documented command-line options or `ssh_config`. :D

Comment: Difference is a list with servers, because you can't really remember all host names when it's over a hundred of them. Difference is tabbed/docking interface to open windows side-by-side. To type in many consoles at once.

Comment: This shows advantages of the "do one thing an do it well" approach. I just tested in Debian. Tab completions for `ssh` in Bash parse server-wide and user's `ssh_config` and `known_hosts`, plus `/etc/hosts`; this provides a list of known servers. To get tabs or panes you pick a terminal emulator or/and a terminal multiplexer that fits your needs. I'm not saying this approach will immediately solve your problem. I'm only noticing it's possible you'll find a client that solves the main issue but does not provide other functionalities you find useful in another do-it-all client.

Answer (score 0):

After asking nicely, XShell have added PKCS#11 certificate support in build 0093.